# 2 different AVG column in 1 table with select

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make an table that shows an AVG of pickpockets in district with markets and an AVG of pickpockets in districts without Market.

i would like to have the output like this:

```
district with market | district without market
----------------------------------------------
269                  | 34
```

but instead i get this:

```
district with market | district without market
----------------------------------------------
269                  | 269
34                   | 34
```

this is the query i used:

```
select round(avg(average),0) as districts_with_markets, round(avg(average),0) as districts_without_markets
from zakkenrollerij
where wijk in (select district
              from market)
union
select round(avg(average),0) as districts_with_markets, round(avg(average),0) as districts_without_markets
from zakkenrollerij
where wijk not in (select district
              from market)
```

I hope someone can help me :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `distict` is unique in `market`, then you can do this with a `left join` and conditional aggregation:

```
select round(avg(case when m.district is not null then average end), 0) as districts_with_markets, 
       round(avg(case when m.district is null then average end), 0) as districts_without_markets
from zakkenrollerij z left join
     market m
     on m.district = z.wijk;
```

If this is not the case, then use a subquery and a flag:

```
select round(avg(case when hasMarketFlag then average end), 0) as districts_with_markets, 
       round(avg(case when not hasMarketFlag then average end), 0) as districts_without_markets
from (select z.*,
             (exists (select 1
                      from market m
                      where m.district = z.wijk
                     )
             ) as hasMarketFlag
      from zakkenrollerij z;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
Select sum(dist_with_markets) as district_with_markets, 
       sum(dist_without_markets) as district_without_markets
from
(
select round(avg(average),0) as dist_with_markets, 0 as dist_without_markets
from zakkenrollerij
where wijk in (select district
              from market)
union
select 0 as dist_with_markets, round(avg(average),0) as dist_without_markets
from zakkenrollerij
where wijk not in (select district
              from market)                                                          ) a;
```

Hope this helps:-)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT ROUND( AVG( with_markets ) ) AS districts_with_markets,
       ROUND( AVG( without_markets ) ) AS without_markets
FROM ( SELECT average AS with_markets
              NULL AS without_markets
       FROM zakkenrollerij
       WHERE wijk IN ( SELECT district
                       FROM market )
       UNION
       SELECT NULL,
              average
       FROM zakkenrollerij
       WHERE wijk NOT IN ( SELECT district
                           FROM market )
     ) AS tempTable;
```

This starts by forming a list of all the values of `average` within `zakkenrollerij` that qualify as `within`.  No attempt to perform calculations is made at this stage.  The second column is for those values that qualify as `without` - all of its values will be set to `NULL` at this stage.

This list is then joined vertically with its `without` counterpart using the `UNION` operator.

The joined list then has the `ROUND( AVG() )` operations performed upon its columns.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You are now going trough the table twice, selecting the same variable twice under different names:

**round(avg(average),0)** as districts_with_markets, **round(avg(average),0)** as districts_without_market

Instead of uniting the tables afterwards you can use CASE to select a variable with specific conditions. This should give the wanted result:

```
select round(avg(case when wijk in (select district from market) then average else null end),0) as districts_with_markets, 
     round(avg(case when wijk not in (select district from market) then average else null end),0) as districts_without_markets
from zakkenrollerij
```